# PDF: is this a valid font name ? - #82l#82r#82o#83S#83V#83b#83N

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation

I am using a PDF converter library to embed fonts in a PDF file.

However there is a problem with some documents (japanese?) where the library cannot recognize a fontname correctly

```
/FontName /#82l#82r#82o#83S#83V#83b#83N
```

is this a valid name for a font ?

If yes - could someone give me a reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Shift JIS encoding ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS )

Take a look at this old mail from the Ghostscript mailing list for a list of font names: <strike>http://www.ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-cvs/2002-April/001599.html</strike>
https://web.archive.org/web/20100131034139/http://www.ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-cvs/2002-April/001599.html

Comment: it's pretty long, but Ctrl-F for "japanese-shift-jis"

Comment: @kb: I am a real newbie regarding all this PDF and Font stuff. So this might be looking like a stupid question: are there some .ttf files which contains the mentioned font? Are there some tools to display fontnames from .ttf files ? (I have also .otf and .ttc files)

Comment: i'm afraid the only pdf parsing i've done remapped it to the standard windows fonts, however MS-Gothic is a commercial font i believe, but reading the textual identifier from fonts should be quite easy, try googling for the font fileformat, the name should be somewhere in the header easily parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good and detailed explanation in the usenet (group `comp.fonts`)

... from user `ken` ...

see the PDF Reference, in 1.7 version, on page 57, 'Section 
3.2.4 Name Objects':

"Beginning with PDF 1.2, any character except null (character code 0) may be included in a name by writing its 2-digit hexadecimal code, preceded by the number sign character (#); see implementation notes 3 and 4 in Appendix H.

This syntax is required to represent any of the delimiter or white-space characters or the number sign character itself; it is recommended but not required for characters whose codes are outside the range 33 (!) to 126 (~). The examples shown in Table 3.3 are 
valid literal names in PDF 1.2 and later. "

**Edit**: sorry, I don't know howto add a reference to the usenet article here

Answer (score 0):

ANA issue PDFs with the ＭＳゴシック (MS Gothic, a font designed for use in Japan) font named using Shift JIS encoding, but without any font embedding. The fonts that PDF viewers on Linux (or Android) substitute for this do a poor job of rendering those PDFs. This is, in fact, the font name that is identified in this question.

The real solution would be for ANA to use a different font or to embed the font in their PDFs. The font is not free and cross-platform, and there does not appear to be a reliable free to use substitute. Even if we could find an alternative and put in an alias, the use of the Shift JIS encoding seems to defeat attempts to alias the font because the Shift JIS sequences result in invalid UTF-8 encodings, and it appears there is no way to match the resulting string in fonts.conf

Acrobat for Linux (if you can still find it) and Foxit both do a passable job of dealing with these files, but anything that uses poppler will mess it up badly.